# Basis free proof of the Frobenius formula

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H<G$ a subgroup. Let $V$ be a representation of $H$ with character $\chi$. The Frobenius formula states that the character of the induced representation $\text{Ind}_H^G(V) := \mathbb{k}G\otimes_{\mathbb{k}H}V$ is given by:

$$\chi_{\text{Ind}_H^GV}(g) = \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{\substack{x\in G \\x^{-1}gx\in H}}\chi(x^{-1}gx)$$

The usual proof of this fact (for instance the ones in Serre or Fulton&Harris) starts by considering the basis $(g_i \otimes e_j)$ of $\mathbb{k}G\otimes_{\mathbb{k}H}V$, where the $g_i$ are a set of representatives of the cosets $G/H$, and the $e_j$ are a basis of V. Then one studies how an element $g\in G$ acts on $\mathbb{k}G\otimes_{\mathbb{k}H}V$ with respect to this basis, and from this, deduces the above formula.

Now I was wondering: Is there an alternative proof of this, that doesn't involve a choice of basis of $\mathbb{k}G\otimes_{\mathbb{k}H}V$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different approaches to induction of characters, and depending on the approach some things become definitions and some become actual results. My favourite is the following one.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\CF}{CF}\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}\DeclareMathOperator{\Ind}{Ind}$
Let $\CF(G)$ denote the space of class functions on $G$, and similarly for $H$. Each of these spaces is equipped with the usual inner product $\langle-,-\rangle_G$, respectively $\langle-,-\rangle_H$. There is an obvious linear map $$
\Res_{H}^G\colon \CF(G)\to \CF(H),
$$
given by restriction of class functions. From general linear algebra we know that linear maps between inner product spaces have adjoints. Denote the adjoint of $\Res^G_H$ by $\Ind^G_H$, and call it induction. Thus, by definition $\Ind^G_H$ is a linear map from $\CF(H)$ to $\CF(G)$ satisfying, for every $\chi\in \CF(G)$ and every $\psi\in \CF(H)$ that
$$
\langle \Res_H^G\chi,\psi\rangle_{H} = \langle\chi,\Ind_H^G\psi\rangle_G.
$$
The beauty of this approach is that firstly, you do not have to pull a magical formula for the induction of a representation out of the hat (yet) — existence of adjoints of linear maps is just a general fact; and secondly notice that Frobenius reciprocity becomes true by definition.

The formula you want to prove also follows almost immediately: the adjoint of a linear map is unique, and it is completely determined by pairing $\Ind^G_G\psi$ with a basis for the space $\CF(G)$. Take as your basis the set of characteristic functions of the various conjugacy classes, i.e. for each conjugacy class $C$, consider the function
$$
f_C(g) = \begin{cases}1:&g\in C\\0:&\text{ else.}\end{cases}
$$
You will find that the defining property $\langle \Res^G_H f_C,\psi\rangle_H = \langle f_C,\Ind^G_H\psi\rangle_G$ for all $C$ immediately gives you your formula.

There is one downside to this approach: the space of class functions has a distinguished subset, the set of characters. We certainly know that the restriction of a character is again a character, namely the character of the restriction of the representation. Wouldn't it be nice if inductions of characters were also always characters? This does not follow formally from the linear algebra, and does require an inspired Frobenius to write down the definition of a representation with the right character.

Comment: So the formula for the character of an induced representation is just a consequence of Frobenius reciprocity!
Also +1 for making me realize that, when translated in terms of class functions, the adjunction of functors $\text{Ind} \dashv \text{Res}$ is just an adjunction in the sense of linear algebra.

Comment: @Fungaria: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a less basis-dependent proof by observing $g\in G$ acts on $$\mathbb kG\otimes_{\mathbb kH}V=\bigoplus_{xH\in G/H}\mathbb k(xH)\otimes_{\mathbb kH}V$$
by preserving the direct sum decomposition. Thus, the trace of $g$ acting on $\mathbb kG\otimes_{\mathbb kH}V$ is the sum over cosets $xH\in G/H$ fixed by $g$ of the trace of $g$ on $\mathbb k(xH)\otimes_{\mathbb kH}V$. That is,
$$\begin{align*}
\chi_{\mathrm{Ind}_H^G V}(g)&=\sum_{\substack{xH\in G/H\\gxH=xH}}\mathrm{tr}(g;\mathbb k(xH)\otimes_{\mathbb kH}V)\\
&=\sum_{\substack{xH\in G/H\\x^{-1}gx\in H}}\chi_V(x^{-1}gx)\\
&=\frac1{|H|}\sum_{\substack{x\in G\\x^{-1}gx\in H}}\chi_V(x^{-1}gx).
\end{align*}$$
Here, the second inequality is given by observing $g$ acts on $\mathbb k(xH)\otimes_{\mathbb kH}V$ as $x\otimes v\mapsto gx\otimes v=x(x^{-1}gx)\otimes v=x\otimes (x^{-1}gx)v$ since $x^{-1}gx\in H$.